# Finding All Cliques of an Undirected Graph

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithm, clique-problem

How can I list all cliques of an Undirected Graph ? (Not all maximal cliques, like the Bron-Kerbosch algorithm)

Comment: I'm still searching for an algorithm. But I found some codes for the Bron-Kerbosch algorithm (but the problem, that this algorithm returns all **maximal** cliques, not all cliques)

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/boost/graph/bron_kerbosch_all_cliques.hpp

Comment: this is not how StackOverflow work. We help you solve specific code questions, not homework-type algorithm questions. If you have specific code you tried using, and doesn't work for some reason, please share it. Otherwise, try asking at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

The optimal solution is like this because in a complete graph there are 2^n cliques. Consider all subsets of nodes using a recursive function. And for each subset if all the edges are present between nodes of the subset, add 1 to your counter: (This is almost a pseudocode in C++)

```
int clique_counter = 0;
int n; //number of nodes in graph
//i imagine nodes are numbered from 1 to n

void f(int x, vector <int> &v){ //x is the current node
    if(x == n){
        bool is_clique = true;
        for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++){
            for(int j = i + 1; j < v.size(); j++){
                if(there is not an edge between node v[i] and v[j]) //it can't be clique
                    is_clique = false;
            }
        }
        if(is_clique == true){
            clique_counter++;
        }
        return;
    }

    //if x < n

    f(x + 1, v);

    v.push_back(x);
    f(x + 1, v);
    v.pop_back();
}


int main(){
    vector <int> v;
    f(1, v);
    cout << clique_counter << endl;

    return 0;
}
```