# Find all common elements and combinations in tuples using Python

Tags: python, iteration, combinations

I am trying to group all values together that share common elements across tuples - essentially find groups of numbers that for any combination of them (no order required) - I have the tuple.  For example, if I have the following set of tuples:

```
(1,2),(1,3),(1,5),(1,6),(2,3),(2,5),(2,7),(3,5),(3,7),(3,9)
```

I want to understand all the elements that are in common.  For this example, this would be:

```
1, 2, 3, 5  (since I have any combination of 1,2,3 and 5)
2, 3, 7 (since I have any combination of 2,3 and 7)
1, 6 (since I have any combination of 1 and 6)
3, 9 (since I have any combination of 3 and 9)
```

Any thoughts on how to solve this?

Comment: The requirements aren't clear each line just says *since I have any combination of*.

Comment: I believe mcfly means that there could be a `(1,2)` or a `(2,1)` and they'd be treated the same

Comment: Why isn't `1,6` on the first line then? It's not clear to me what *since I have any combination* means.

Comment: yes - exactly.  I don't care if it is (1,2) or (2,1) - these are the same in my example.  (1,6) isn't on the first line because I don't have (2,6) or (3,6) or (5,6).

Comment: This problem is called: "Finding All Cliques of an Undirected Graph". In this instance every tuple is an edge that connects two nodes.

Comment: @mcfly so this is a graph problem? How about rephrase this so it's clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: Please refer to pseudo code in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37999282/finding-all-cliques-of-an-undirected-graph

Comment: I didn't realize it was a graph problem until mentioned - thanks - I will look at the cliques of an undirected graph.

Comment: @alfasin: It's probably called "Finding all maximal cliques", since any subgraph of a clique is a clique. ;)

Comment: @anon: Because they're cliques, but they're not "maximal cliques". They are included in larger cliques. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_(graph_theory)#Definitions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned by @alfasin, you're looking for the maximal [cliques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_(graph_theory)) in your graph.

> A clique, C, in an undirected graph G = (V, E) is a subset of the
>   vertices, C ⊆ V, such that every two distinct vertices are adjacent.
>
> A maximal clique is a clique that cannot be extended by including one
>   more adjacent vertex, that is, a clique which does not exist
>   exclusively within the vertex set of a larger clique.

[NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9.1/overview.html) with [`find_cliques`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9.1/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.clique.find_cliques.html#networkx.algorithms.clique.find_cliques) is your friend:

```
>>> import networkx as nx
>>> G = nx.Graph([(1,2),(1,3),(1,5),(1,6),(2,3),(2,5),(2,7),(3,5),(3,7),(3,9)])
>>> list(nx.find_cliques(G))
[[3, 9], [3, 2, 1, 5], [3, 2, 7], [6, 1]]
```

If you want to define your graph as the union of small cliques and see if they merge to larger cliques, you can use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to iterate over all the edges of your input cliques and add them to the graph:

```
import networkx as nx
from itertools import combinations

G = nx.Graph()

cliques = [(1,2,3),(1,2,4),(1,3,4),(2,3,4)]

for clique in cliques:
  for vertices in combinations(clique, r=2):
    G.add_edge(*vertices)

print(list(nx.find_cliques(G)))
# [[1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Comment: well - this is fantastic - thanks to all for steering me toward graphs!

Comment: @mcfly: That's what I love most about Python. Have a problem? Someone at Google, NASA or MIT probably had it too and wrote some cool library to solve it. :)

Comment: @EricDuminil thanks for posting this solution, I was not aware of this library!

Comment: @EricDuminil: couldn't agree more!  this is a great library - look forward to seeing what else it can do!

Comment: @EricDuminil - is it possible to extend this to larger tuples?  For example, can i have (1,2,3),(1,2,4),(1,3,4),(2,3,4) and get a single clique of (1,2,3,4)?

Comment: @mcfly I wouldn't expect it to work since `(2,5)` represents an edge between nodes 2 and 5. But how would one interpret: `(2,5,9)` ?

Comment: @alfasin - are there any other theories you may know of that consider this question?

Comment: @alfasin: An edge is a 2-vertex clique and a graph can be designed as a collection of edges, so why not define a graph as a collection of 3-vertex cliques? `(2,5,9)` can be interpreted as 3 edges `(2,5)`, `(5,9)` and `(2,9)`. You just need to iterate over the vertex combinations.